# Airflow - Using jinja macros as variables to create dynamic DAG

Tags: python, jinja2, airflow

I need to create a dynamic DAG that will have a separate task for each date in DAG variables or (next_execution_date - 1 day) period by default (it is necessary to use the execution date of the dag).
An example of my dag:

```
dag_vars = Variable.get("dag_dates", deserialize_json=True) # dag_dates = {"dag_start_dt": "NULL", "dag_end_dt": "NULL"}, but can be different dates
DAG_NAME = "dag_test"

def get_params(vars):
    if vars["dag_start_dt"] == "NULL":
        start_dt = "{{(next_execution_date - macros.timedelta(days=1))}}"
    else:
        start_dt = vars["dag_start_dt"]
    if vars["dag_end_dt"] == "NULL":
        end_dt = "{{ next_execution_date }}"
    else:
        end_dt = vars["dag_end_dt"]
    return start_dt, end_dt

start_dag_params, end_dag_params = get_params(dag_vars)

def get_dag_daterange(start_date, end_date):
    for n in range(int((end_date - start_date).days)):
         yield start_date + timedelta(n)


dag = DAG(
    dag_id=DAG_NAME,
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval= None,
    concurrency=1,
    max_active_runs=1,
)

with dag:
    start_date, end_date = start_dag_params, end_dag_params
    for one_date in get_dag_daterange(start_date, end_date):
        task_1 = PostgresOperator(
            sql = """CALL test_procedure({l_one_date})""".format(l_one_date=one_date),
            task_id = "test_procedure_{l_one_date}".format(l_one_date=str(one_date)),
            postgres_conn_id = "xxx",
            pool = "pool_test",
            dag = dag,
            autocommit = True,
        )
```

But I have an error "unsupported operand types for -: 'str' and 'str'".

I know that the reason is in the macro ({{next_execution_date}}), which is parsed at runtime through Jinja, but I don’t know how to solve this problem and how can I use macros as variables in airflow DAG.

I would be glad for any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, [there is no way to access macro out of runtime of some task](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/0199c5d51aa7d34b7e3e8e6aad73ab80b6018e8b/airflow/models/taskinstance.py#L1397).
There could be 2 workarounds:

1. Try to get data without runtime. You can get **next_execution_date** out of runtime with [DAG.next_dagrun_info()](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/0199c5d51aa7d34b7e3e8e6aad73ab80b6018e8b/airflow/models/dag.py#L674) method.
2. Make it in runtime. You can make an ordinary(not dynamic) DAG which contains SubDagOperator, where you can create and trigger (probably) your dynamically created DAG according to data, accessible in runtime.